# using custom css from bootstrap 2 for pelican-bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, pelican

I am very new to both CSS and pelican !
basically, I would like to have a static website using pelican that looks like the website X which is made based on Bootstrap 2. I have installed and now using pelican-bootstrap 3 them (again, I am using bootstrap 3). I have inspected the website X and I can see the "style.css".

I believe I need to utilize this file somehow in my pelican blog. therefore, I have created a folder called, "css" inside the content folder, and put the style.css over there.

In the pelicanconfig.py, I have made these changes,

```
THEME = '/home/mysite/pelican-bootstrap3'
BOOTSTRAP_THEME = 'simplex' 
PYGMENTS_STYLE = 'simplex'

CUSTOM_CSS = 'css/style.css' ##
STATIC_PATHS = ['images', 'css/style.css'] ##if I am not mistaken I am specifying the address inside my content folder.
```

however, I don't see changes, and when I inspect my blog element, the style.css is something different (probably its written based on simplex)

my questions are here
1) are the config parameters correctly set ?
2) does it sound reasonable to copy and paste the other css file from bootstrap2 into this theme ? (I understand I would need to tweak it a little bit).
3) I appreciate any comment

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the *pelican-bootstrap3* theme for Pelican.

If I understand correctly, you want your Pelican-based site to look like a Bootstrap 2 site. If that is indeed the case, it makes no sense to use *pelican-bootstrap3*, because as the name implies, it is based on Bootstrap 3, which looks different than Bootstrap 2. Moreover, in order for the `CUSTOM_CSS` variable to work at all in the theme, you must also tell Pelican where to copy the css file, like so:

```
EXTRA_PATH_METADATA = {
    'extra/custom.css': {'path': 'css/custom.css'}
}
```

And even if you do that, you will still not get the looks of "website X", as you call it, because the HTML in Bootstrap 3 (on which the theme is based) is differently structured than the HTML in Bootstrap 2.

My advice: use one of the few Bootstra 2 based themes available in the [pelican-themes](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-themes) repository.